# Iterate through data in a related table correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am working on something that should be simple, but I am having trouble because I am new to rails.

I have a table called TimeSheet and table called Entry.

I am working in my time_sheet show view and want to iterate through the related entries on my time_sheet.

MY models are setup like this.  A user has_many :time_sheet.  A time sheet belongs_to :user and has_many :entries.  And entries belong_to: time_sheet

My time sheet view looks like:

```
  <% @current.each do |t| %>
  <td><%= t.entries :customer_name %></td>   
  <td><%= t.entries :order_number %></td>
  <td><%= t.entries :time_in %></td>
  <td><%= t.entries :time_out %></td> 
  <% end %>
```

My controller for the time_sheet show is:

```
 def show
    if current_user
    @current = current_user.time_sheets.entries
  else
    redirect_to new_user_session_path, notice: 'You are not logged in.'
  end
```

I am getting strange output that looks like this for each iteration:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Entry:0xb59dfcc8>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a guess, but does `<%= t.customer_name %>` print what you are looking for? You are already fetching all of the entries in your controller.

Comment: I get this error when I try that. undefined method `customer_name' for #<TimeSheet:0xb9f65c98>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you already

```
@current = current_user.time_sheets.entries
```

and

```
<% @current.each do |t| %>
```

So the "t" is each entry of your related time_sheets. Are you sure there is another entries? Even assume the statement don't have syntax error.

```
<td><%= t.entries :customer_name %></td>
```

How about like this.

```
   def show
        if current_user
        @time_sheets = current_user.time_sheets
      else
        redirect_to new_user_session_path, notice: 'You are not logged in.'
      end
   end
```

In view:

```
  <% @time_sheets.each do |sheet| %>
     <% sheet.entries.each do |t| %>
        <td><%= t.customer_name %></td>   
        <td><%= t.order_number %></td>
        <td><%= t.time_in %></td>
        <td><%= t.time_out %></td> 
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

I assume customer_name, order_name are the fields name in your entry table.